# Pandas dataframe column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which I have collected from a MongoDB.

The column names are a series of dates, ie. 4/7/20, 4/8/20, etc.

What I want to do is find the most recent date which has a column name the same as the date, because I want to delete all other date columns before writing it to a PostgreSQL database.

I was intending:

1. Set a variable with today's date
2. Loop through the column names comparing with today's date
3. If exists, retain the variable name
4. If it does not, reduce the date by 1 and check again until I get a match.

I am trying to get a list of column names from the dataframe, but when I run

```
    collection = client['DB_Name']['DB_Collection']
    
    df = collection.find()
    
    data_pandas = pd.DataFrame(list(df))
    
    index_list = list(data_pandas.index.values.tolist()) 
    
    today = date.today()
    
    today = today.strftime('X%m/X%d/%Y').replace('X0','X').replace('X','')
    
    print(df.columns)
```

I get an error:

> 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'columns'

The data frame looks fine from the IDE. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I've removed "Mods - feel free to delete question" from the self-answer. I guess this means there was just a trivial error stopping this working.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB returns a cursor object, which you'll need to comprehend before passing to pandas. Take a look here:

[How can I load data from mongodb collection into pandas' DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805304/how-can-i-load-data-from-mongodb-collection-into-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks for your help - that is what I have done though? (Edited the source code in my original question to add more detail)

Answer (score 0):

Was calling `print(df.columns)` instead of `data_pandas.columns`.